# Maximum on BizTalk iterator functoid

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

Does the Iterator functoid in BizTalk 2006 R2 have a maximum or some other way to reset the value? I'm seeing the returned value starting back at 1 several times throughout the EDI document I'm generating without a clear pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It should not reset, if there was a max value it would reset at the same point each time.

Things that you could check are:

- Is the data that you are importing structured with a list in various nodes, that it is reseting once per node.
- Is the application pool recycling during the document generation, this could be caused by a memory leak
- For the same document does it happen in the same place each time? There could be some special characters that cause an exception and then a reset
- Are there any exceptions in the event log